# Text cleaning python code

Tags: python, string-parsing, data-cleaning

*My question is different because the answer conveys the deeper problem which is concise code vs forest like variables.  I believe I deserve reputation points for pointing out the clarity of concise shortened variable code is for finding the logical problem.*

I'm working on a Dataquest tutorial *Great site for data Python btw* and having problems with this string cleaning code.  The cleaned string comes back exactly as the original with nothing parsed out.

here's the code, I tried to make it as concise as possible:

```
ss = open('story.txt', 'r').read()
cc = [",", ".", ";", "\n", "'"]

print(ss + "\n\n\n")

cleaned_story = ""
def clean_text(x, y):
    cs = x
    for e in y:
        cs.replace(e, "")
    cs = cs.lower()
    return cs

cleaned_story = clean_text(ss, cc)
print(cleaned_story)
print(type(cleaned_story)) #this is just for weird test
```

Comment: Read the documentation on `str.replace` function. It **returns** a new string. Python strings are immutable, and cannot be changed in place.

Comment: Also maybe helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: No I realized it as soon as I shortened the variables to 1 or 2 digits.  That's a good lesson because if the code is too cumbersome it could look like a forest.  I lost two reputation points when I should have gained some for some code style lesson :(

Comment: Yes, thank you for providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I found the problem.  Making the code more concise helped me see the error right away.  I forgot to assign `cs` variable to itself after using the replace method.

I love Python so much!

Thanks StackOverflow.  You are God!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were calling the function .replace(), which returns a modified version of the string, but not assigining anything to the return value. I changed the line to

```
cs = cs.replace(e, "")
```

and it worked fine.

```
ss = "this text, it is... a test;"
cc = [",", ".", ";", "\n", "'"]

print(ss + "\n\n\n")

cleaned_story = ""
def clean_text(x, y):
    cs = x
    for e in y:
        cs = cs.replace(e, "")
    cs = cs.lower()
    return cs

cleaned_story = clean_text(ss, cc)
print(cleaned_story)
print(type(cleaned_story)) #this is just for weird test
```

Comment: yep...the original code was a forest so I shortened the variable names for more visibility and immediately identified the problem.  Thank you for your help :)